# How to install a Java .jar file as a Java extension?

Tags: install, java

I'm on MacOS 11.6 running java 19.0.2.  According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html), I should be able to use extension classes by putting .jar files in:

> jre/lib/ext

The closest directory I could find was

> Library/Java/Extensions

However this did not work.  For this particular example I am just trying to use junit, but in general were is my extensions folder if the one I have is not correct.

I do not want to use any additional tools, but want to classes found per the docs above in the extensions folder.

Seems like more relevant documentation is here - [Oracle - JRE 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/).

Comment: Support for the ext directory was removed in Java 11 see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/migration-guide.pdf) and [JEP 220](https://openjdk.org/jeps/220)

Comment: @greg - thank, I wish I could find reference material for Java 19, and the correct way to do this.   I could not find it in the link I posted above.

Comment: As JEP 220 says the extensions mechanism has been completely removed as it didn't really fit with the new module system and it wasn't used very much. Jars just have to be put on the normal classpath / modulepath now.